Can there be fully homomorphic encryption with this property?
Lets say Alice has data D and wants to send this data for Bob to process it with algorithm A. Is it possible to encrypt D so that it can only be used to run algorithm A? Alice and Bob will communicate just two times. When she sends the data and when he sends the result.

Why do you need this? The data is already encrypted and processes or not it can only be decrypted with proper private key.

@kelalaka Say D_1,D_2,...,D_n are data points that are encrypted and sended to a server to run a ML algorithm A. Results of the algorithm can be public, but the data should only be used for algorithm A. And for nothing else.

@kelalaka Let me add that people sending data points are different.

There seem to be some issues about how this question is worded. How can "data D... run algorithm A"? Furthermore, data can always be run through an algorithm, it's the question if the output would be useful. Now we might be able to work around these issues but 1. it should not be necessary and 2. clarifying these issues may take you closer towards an answer yourself. Modeling the system correctly is one part of the solving a problem after all.
